# Stepper motor control with Sparkfun Autodriver L6470 in Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, electronics

I am struggling and cannot get this to work all (stepper motor doesn't do anything, not convinced even energising as can turn manually with no resistance)

[image]

Pins used from a Raspberry Pi 4B to a Sparkfun L6470
[image]

Simple code tried:

```
import spidev
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# GPIO pins
CS_PIN = 8      # GPIO pin for CS (Chip Select)
SCK_PIN = 11    # GPIO pin for SCK (SPI Clock)
MOSI_PIN = 10   # GPIO pin for MOSI (Master Out Slave In)
MISO_PIN = 9    # GPIO pin for MISO (Master In Slave Out)
STBY_PIN = 17   # GPIO pin for STBY/RESET
RST_PIN = 25    # GPIO pin for RST/NSD

# Initialize SPI
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)  # Open SPI bus 0, device 0
spi.max_speed_hz = 1000000  # Set SPI speed

# Initialize GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(CS_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SCK_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MOSI_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MISO_PIN, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(STBY_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RST_PIN, GPIO.OUT)


def send_command(command):
    GPIO.output(CS_PIN, GPIO.LOW)  # Enable SPI communication
    spi.xfer2([command])
    GPIO.output(CS_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)  # Disable SPI communication

# Reset the L6470
def reset_l6470():
    GPIO.output(RST_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    GPIO.output(RST_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.01)

# Initialize L6470
def initialize_l6470():
    send_command(0xC0)  # Set parameter command
    send_command(0x00)  # Set step mode to full step (0x00 for full step, refer to datasheet)

# Move the motor
def move_motor(steps, speed):
    send_command(0x51)  # Move command
    send_command(steps & 0xFF)  # Number of steps (LSB)
    send_command((steps >> 8) & 0xFF)  # Number of steps (MSB)
    send_command(speed & 0xFF)  # Speed (LSB)
    send_command((speed >> 8) & 0xFF)  # Speed (MSB)

try:
    GPIO.output(STBY_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)  # Enable the motor driver

    reset_l6470()
    initialize_l6470()

    move_motor(400, 200)  # Move 400 steps at speed 200 (adjust as needed)
    time.sleep(2)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    GPIO.output(STBY_PIN, GPIO.LOW)  # Disable the motor driver
    spi.close()  # Close the SPI bus
    GPIO.cleanup()  # Clean up GPIO pins
```

When I run in Geany for the first time,  I get runtime errors: the channel is already in use, continue anyway for:

```
GPIO.setup(CS_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SCK_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MOSI_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MISO_PIN, GPIO.IN)
```

on reruns I get just: program exits with code 0

I get no errors re: spidev or rPi.GPIO - appear to be installed correctly.
Sparkfun on board power set to external and set to send data to prev board (on board jumpers)
I have tried different stepper motors - so know the stepper works
Sparkfun board getting power ok and separate motor power ok

Any help welcomed!, I have toiled over this and no luck so far. Any obvious mistakes or oversights I have made?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Seb Wilson. There's a [Getting started with the autodriver](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-autodriver) tutorial, and it looks like the steps are different than what you have listed. Notably, they've got a library they're already written for use with the device, and that could help eliminate any potential coding issues. Also notable is that there are some pretty clear cautions there that the ribbon cable connectors alternate and there are some clear images of how the cables should be made up. Have you tried following along with the tutorial?